# "Fermat's last theorem" and anabelian geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, anabelian-geometry

Do I remember a remark in "Sketch of a program" or "Letter to Faltings" correctly, that acc. to Grothendieck [anabelian geometry](http://www.math.okayama-u.ac.jp%2F~h-naka%2Fzoo%2Fpeacock%2FNTM.ps) should not only enable finiteness proofs, but a proof of FLT too? If yes, how?

Edit: [In this](http://www.ams.org/notices/201009/rtx100901106p.pdf) transcript, Illusie makes a remark that Grothendieck looked for a connection between "FLT" and "higher stacks". BTW, [here](http://madameboisvert.blogspot.com/2009/04/discovering-paca.html) a note on (acc. to Illusie) Grothendieck's [favored landscape](http://www.cabris.fr/#/galerie/sample-album-1/point-de-vue-9/).

Comment: The "Sketch of a program" is available at http://www.grothendieckcircle.org/.
On page 40 of the pdf-file there is certainly a reference to FLT.

Comment: Thanks. Has anyone an idea what he had in mind about that?   

Comment: relevant here https://agrothendieck.github.io/divers/galoisI.pdf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the papers of Minhyong Kim. For example, begin by looking at the MR review 2181717 of his paper  Invent. Math. 161 (2005), no. 3, 629--656.

Comment: Thanks! I'd be happy about further explanations on arithmetics and anabelian geometry.

Comment: See also http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahmki/cambridgews.pdf

Answer (score 6):

As Minhyong Kim points out in one of his papers on unipotent fundamental group- it is not quite clear how the section conjecture would imply Faltings theorem. The nature of implication (i.e. section conjecture implies Faltings or FLT) may be known to some experts but I don't know if it is explicitly written in literature.

Comment: I believe that it is not yet known that the section conjecture implies Mordell's conjecture (Faltings' theorem).

Comment: At some point Deligne thought he had a proof that the section conjecture implied Mordell, but the proof doesn't work. This is all explained in an appendix by Deligne to a paper of Stix: http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5009